# Javascript moment Is within a date range api

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Currently using http://momentjs.com/

Is there a function I can use as below to find out if array of dates fall within a single day?

Example:

```
Events0 - 21-12-2014 1130
Events1 - 24-12-2014 1030 
Events2 - 24-12-2014 1130
Events3 - 24-12-2014 0800 until 26-12-2014
Events4 - 28-12-2014
```

I want momentjs to return me all events that is within 24-12-2014

So it should return

```
Event1
Event2
Event3
```

I tried below but not working well

```
    var events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {

        if (event.start.isSame($scope.selectedDate)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Momentjs does not do this OOTB - check this plug in for ranges. https://github.com/gf3/moment-range

Comment: @limelights This must be done before without using any libraries

Comment: Okay, how are you filtering these dates? On todays date? Or are you just looking to group them and get the group with the highest count?

Comment: @limelights <code>var events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
// filter here
});</code> Trying to use the filter but not working well

Comment: @limelights questions updated with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using these conditions

```
 var events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {

        if ((event.start <= $scope.selectedDate && event.end >= $scope.selectedDate) ||
             event.start.isSame($scope.selectedDate, 'day')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I still prefer to use moment.js! Any idea if i can convert that to use moment library?